# Weebly editor inserts destination url into text hyperlinks

Tags: url, hyperlink, editor, weebly

When I insert a url into a text hyperlink, the Weebly editor inserts the destination url into the middle of the text I'm trying to use as the link text.

I highlight the text to be used as the link, click on the hyperlink icon in the pop-up box, insert the url into the website url box and click back into the link text.

The link should read "Blue Cat Quartet" but the hyperlink url has been inserted into the middle of the text and shows as:

Blue Cwww.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100093984416297at Quartet

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place for this question. Please try clearing your browser cache and if that doesn’t help try reaching out to Weebly Support for help.

Comment: Sorry!  Point taken.